# Plaintext XOR'd with keylength-shifted plaintext

Tags: xor, vigenere

While solving a (easy...) Project Euler cipher problem this week I repeatedly saw instructions for breaking ciphers after identifying the keylength as:

> 'shift the ciphertext by that key length and XOR it with itself. This
>   removes the key and leaves you with plaintext XORed with the plaintext
>   shifted the length of the key'

So I can understand how this drops the key out the equation, but I don't see how plaintext XORd with plaintext shifted by keylength is any more tractable.  In the many references I saw about this, no one followed up with how to solve the plaintext^shiftedPlaintext piece.  It doesn't seem that different than plaintext^keyPhrase really.

What am I missing about why this makes the problem easier to solve? What approaches deal with this part of the problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, if we have plaintext^shiftedPlaintext, what we have is the values $P_i \oplus P_{i+k}$, where $k$ is the length of the shift.

What does this imply?  Well, if we consider the values $P_i \oplus P_{i+k}$, $P_{i+k} \oplus P_{i+2k}$, $P_{i+2k} \oplus P_{i+3k}$, ... we get a chain where, if we guess one of the values $P_{i+nk}$ for some $n$, we can immediately reconstruct all other plaintext bytes in the chain; thus giving us the correct value for every $k$th plaintext byte.

That can be exploited in several ways.  One approach is crib dragging; we guess that a common word (the canonical crib for English is "the") occurs at a specific location, and see what that implies for other places in the plaintext; if it makes sense, then it is likely correct (and we have a large amount of plaintext; that gives useful context for other cribs); if it doesn't make sense, we try our crib elsewhere.

In addition, if the plaintext includes spaces, then a useful fact of ASCII can be useful; alphabetical letters have bit 6 set, spaces have bit 6 clear (and while numbers and punctuation also have bit 6 clear, those are comparatively rare).  So, if we see that the value of $P_i \oplus P_{i+k}$ has bit 6 set, then a good guess is that either $P_i$ or $P_{i+k}$ is a space; that acts as a 1 character crib.